# Pair of two-variable cubic polynomial equations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, polynomials, algebraic-equations

Let us consider the following system of two polynomial equations
of third order for two real numbers $x_1,x_2$: 
$$x_i (x_i + 2) (x_i + 4) - 2 a_i (x_1 + x_2 + 4) = 0,$$ $i =1,2$. 
Here $a_1 >0$ and $a_2 >0$. It is necessary to prove that for 
any set of positive numbers $(a_1,a_2)$ there exists a unique solution of
the system obeying $x_1 > 0$ and $x_2 >0$. In this case one can readily prove that 
the functions $x_i = x_i(a_1,a_2)$  ($i =1,2$)  are  smooth in ${\mathbb R}_{+}^2$. 
Remark: for $x_1 + x_2 + 4 \neq 0$ the summing of two equations leads us to the relation 
$x_1^2 + x_2^2 - x_1 x_2 + 2 (x_1 + x_2) = 2 (a_1 + a_2)$.

Answer (score 4):

Solving the first equation for $x_2$ yields 
$$ x_{{2}}={\frac {{x_{{1}}}^{3}}{2\;a_{{1}}}}+3\,{\frac {{x_{{1}}}^{2}}{a_{{1}
}}}-{\frac { \left( a_{{1}}-4 \right) x_{{1}}}{a_{{1}}}}-4
$$
This cubic is $0$ at $x_1 = -4$ and $-1 \pm \sqrt{1+2 a_1}$.  It is convex and increasing for
$x_1 > -1 + \sqrt{1+2 a_1}$.  Similarly, for the second equation, with indices $1$ and $2$ interchanged.  From this it is easy to see that the two curves intersect exactly once in the first quadrant.

Comment: Dear Robert Israel, thank you very much! Your proof is done in a geometric style which is  close (to my opinion) to  that of  V.I. Arnol'd.